# Spark sql Dataframe - import sqlContext.implicits._

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have main that creates spark context:

```
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
    import sqlContext.implicits._
```

Then creates dataframe and does filters and validations on the dataframe.

```
    val convertToHourly = udf((time: String) => time.substring(0, time.indexOf(':')) + ":00:00")

    val df = sqlContext.read.schema(struct).format("com.databricks.spark.csv").load(args(0))
    // record length cannot be < 2 
    .na.drop(3)
    // round to hours
    .withColumn("time",convertToHourly($"time"))
```

This works great.

BUT When I try moving my validations to another file by sending the dataframe to

```
function ValidateAndTransform(df: DataFrame) : DataFrame = {...}
```

that gets the Dataframe & does the validations and transformations: It seems like I need the

```
 import sqlContext.implicits._
```

> To avoid the error:    “value $ is not a member of StringContext”
>   that happens on line:
>            .withColumn("time",convertToHourly(**$**"time"))

But to use the  `import sqlContext.implicits._`
I also need the `sqlContext` either defined in the new file like so:

```
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
```

or send it to the

```
function ValidateAndTransform(df: DataFrame) : DataFrame = {...}
function
```

I feel like the separation I'm trying to do to 2 files (main & validation) is not done correctly...

Any idea on how to design this? Or simply send the sqlContext to the function?

Thanks!

Comment: When I want to separate things like that I just pass SQLContext in the constructor of the new class and then I import sqlContext.implicits._ once per each class. I couldn't come up with anything better so I vote this question up and wait for better sugestions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can work with a singleton instance of the SQLContext. You can take a look at this example in the [spark repository](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/SqlNetworkWordCount.scala)

```
/** Lazily instantiated singleton instance of SQLContext */
object SQLContextSingleton {

  @transient  private var instance: SQLContext = _

  def getInstance(sparkContext: SparkContext): SQLContext = {
    if (instance == null) {
      instance = new SQLContext(sparkContext)
    }
    instance
  }
}
...
//And wherever you want you can do
val sqlContext = SQLContextSingleton.getInstance(rdd.sparkContext)
import sqlContext.implicits._
```

Comment: Thanks! I did use the singleton object but in my case I want it created only once so did:   object SQLContextSingleton {

  @transient var instance: SQLContext = _
}                                                                                                             then initialized it from main, and used it on validations.                     Thanks for the help!